# How to redirect to root route with a middleware in Node.Js Express and Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

I want to redirect to root route after login. In that root route there is a middleware to check if the user has an "admin" or normal "user" role. I loaded the root page with the auth cookie in the browser, but didn't get any user. The result is supposed to be a user/admin after going through the isUser/isAdmin middleware. Admin is already registered in the system. A user will register and then login.

This is my root route.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    
    Title.findAll()
    .then(title => {
  
      NavItems.findAll()
        .then(nitem => {
          NavItem2.findAll()
            .then(navitem2 => {
              NavItem3.findAll()
              .then(navitem3 => {
                   PaperTopic.findAll()
                   .then(topic =>{
                    
                    Paper.findAll({
                      limit: 3,
                      order: [
                                ['postingDate', 'DESC'],
                                ['postingTime', 'DESC']

                      ],
                      include:[{
                        model: PaperTopic,
                        //required: true
                   
                      },{
                        model:Category
                      }]
                    })
                    .then(paper=>{

                       Category.findAll()
                       .then(category=>{

                          NavItem4.findAll()
                          .then(navitem4=>{
                            //console.log(JSON.stringify(paper, null, 2))
                            res.render('home/index', {
                              layout: 'index-layout',
                              title,
                              nitem,
                              navitem2,
                              navitem3,
                              topic,
                              paper,
                              category,
                              navitem4
                              })
                          })
                     
                      })
                    
                       })
                   })
              
              })
             

            })
             

        })

    })

})
```

This is my login route.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

     if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      res.render('auth/login',{
        error_msg: 'Please Give Email And Password',
        layout: false
    })
    }
    else {
      User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } })
        .then(user => {
          if (!user) {
            res.render('auth/login',{
                error_msg: 'This Email Is Not Registered',
                layout: false
            })
          } else {
  
                    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) {
                        const token = jwt.sign({
                            username: user.name,
                            email: user.email,
                            role: user.role
                        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
                            expiresIn: '1h'
                        });
                       
                        res.cookie('ntoken', token,{
                            httpOnly:true
                        })
                        res.redirect('/');
                      

                    }
                    else {
                        res.render('auth/login',{
                            error_msg: 'Invalid Password',
                            layout: false
                        })
                    }

                });
            }

        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  
    }
  
  })
```

Here is my check User middleware.

```
const isUser = (req, res, next) =>{
const token = req.cookies.ntoken;
  try{
   
     const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
     const {username, email, role} = decoded;
     req.username = username;
     req.email = email;
     req.role = role;
     if(req.role == "user"){
      next();
     }else{
        next("Require User Role");
     }
    
  }
  catch (err){
    console.log(err);
    next("Authentication Failure");
   
  }

}
module.exports = isUser;
```

This is my checkAdmin middleware

```
const isAdmin = (req, res, next) =>{
 
    const token = req.cookies.ntoken;
      try{
       
         const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
         const {username, email, role} = decoded;
         req.username = username;
         req.email = email;
         req.role = role;
         if(req.role === "admin"){
          next();
         }else{
           next("Require Admin Role");
          
         }
        
      }
      catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        next("Invalid Token");
       
      }
    
    }
    module.exports = isAdmin;
```

After login I want to redirect to root route with a middleware

```
router.get('/', isUser, async (req, res) => {
  Title.findAll()
  .then(title => {
    NavItems.findAll()
      .then(nitem => {
        NavItem2.findAll()
          .then(navitem2 => {
            NavItem3.findAll()
            .then(navitem3 => {
                 PaperTopic.findAll()
                 .then(topic =>{
                  
                  Paper.findAll({
                    limit: 3,
                    order: [
                              ['postingDate', 'DESC'],
                              ['postingTime', 'DESC']

                    ],
                    include:[{
                      model: PaperTopic,
                      //required: true
                 
                    },{
                      model:Category
                    }]
                  })
                  .then(paper=>{

                     Category.findAll()
                     .then(category=>{

                        NavItem4.findAll()
                        .then(navitem4=>{
                          res.render('home/index', {
                            layout: 'index-layout',
                            name: req.username,
                            email: req.email,
                            role: req.role,
                            title,
                            nitem,
                            navitem2,
                            navitem3,
                            topic,
                            paper,
                            category,
                            navitem4
                            })
                        })
                   
                    })
                  
                     })
                  
                 })
            
            })
           

          })
           

      })

  })

})
```

This is my route for admin after login

```
router.get("/", isAdmin, async (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.email)
  Title.findAll()
  .then(title => {
    //console.log(title);
    NavItems.findAll()
      .then(nitem => {
        NavItem2.findAll()
          .then(navitem2 => {
            NavItem3.findAll()
            .then(navitem3 => {
                 PaperTopic.findAll()
                 .then(topic =>{
                  
                  Paper.findAll({
                    limit: 3,
                    order: [
                              ['postingDate', 'DESC'],
                              ['postingTime', 'DESC']

                    ],
                    include:[{
                      model: PaperTopic,
                      //required: true
                 
                    },{
                      model:Category
                    }]
                  })
                  .then(paper=>{

                     Category.findAll()
                     .then(category=>{

                        NavItem4.findAll()
                        .then(navitem4=>{
                          //console.log(JSON.stringify(paper, null, 2))
                          res.render('home/index', {
                            layout: 'index-layout',
                            name: req.username,
                            email:req.email,                       
                            role: req.role,
                            title,
                            nitem,
                            navitem2,
                            navitem3,
                            topic,
                            paper,
                            category,
                            navitem4
                            })
                        })
                   
                    })
                  
                     })
               
                 })
            
            })
           

          })
           

      })

  })

 })
```

Here is my index-layout.hbs

```
{{#if email}}
   {{#test role "admin"}}
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/admin/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{name}}</a></li>
   {{else}} 
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/user/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{name}}</a></li>
                  
   {{/test}}
    {{else}}
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/auth/register">Register Now!</a></li>
   {{/if}}
```

I tried this. I got the homepage and cookie in the browser. But in the handlebar's page I didn't get the username/email. I am not understanding where the problem is. Is the problem in the routes or in the middleware or somewhere else? Please Help Me...

I have other routes such as /admin/dashboard and /user/dashboard

```
router.get("/admin/dashboard", isUser, async (req, res) => {})
router.get("/user/dashboard", isAdmin, async (req, res) => {})
```

[@76484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3397771/76484?tab=profile)
My new modifications starts from here.

This is my middleware function

```
const checklogin = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.ntoken;
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      if (!decoded) { return next(); }
  
      const { username, email, role } = decoded;
      const user = { email, role, username };
  
      req.user = user; 
      res.locals.user = user; 
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  
    return next();
  };
```

module.exports = checklogin;

This is my app.js

```
const home = require('./routes/home/home');
const auth = require('./routes/auth/auth');
const admin = require('./routes/admin/admin');
const user = require('./routes/user/user');
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/auth', auth)
app.use('/admin', admin)
app.use('/home', homepage)
app.use('/user', user);
```

The logic in my home.js file

```
const checklogin = require('../../middleware/checklogin');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    Title.findAll()
    .then(title => {
      //console.log(title);
      NavItems.findAll()
        .then(nitem => {
          NavItem2.findAll()
            .then(navitem2 => {
              NavItem3.findAll()
              .then(navitem3 => {
                   PaperTopic.findAll()
                   .then(topic =>{
                    
                    Paper.findAll({
                      limit: 3,
                      order: [
                                ['postingDate', 'DESC'],
                                ['postingTime', 'DESC']

                      ],
                      include:[{
                        model: PaperTopic,
                        //required: true
                   
                      },{
                        model:Category
                      }]
                    })
                    .then(paper=>{

                       Category.findAll()
                       .then(category=>{

                          NavItem4.findAll()
                          .then(navitem4=>{
                            //console.log(JSON.stringify(paper, null, 2))
                            res.render('home/index', {
                              layout: 'index-layout',
                              title,
                              nitem,
                              navitem2,
                              navitem3,
                              topic,
                              paper,
                              category,
                              navitem4
                              })
                          })
                     
                      })
                    
                       })
                   
                    
                   })
              
              })
             

            })
             

        })

    })

})




router.get('/', checklogin, async (req, res) => {
 
    if(!(req.user && req.user.role === "admin")){
      res.sendStatus(401);
    }else{
    Title.findAll()
      .then(title => {
        //console.log(title);
        NavItems.findAll()
          .then(nitem => {
            NavItem2.findAll()
              .then(navitem2 => {
                NavItem3.findAll()
                .then(navitem3 => {
                     PaperTopic.findAll()
                     .then(topic =>{
                      
                      Paper.findAll({
                        limit: 3,
                        order: [
                                  ['postingDate', 'DESC'],
                                  ['postingTime', 'DESC']
  
                        ],
                        include:[{
                          model: PaperTopic,
                          //required: true
                     
                        },{
                          model:Category
                        }]
                      })
                      .then(paper=>{
  
                         Category.findAll()
                         .then(category=>{
  
                            NavItem4.findAll()
                            .then(navitem4=>{
                              res.render('home/index', {
                                layout: 'index-layout',
                                title,
                                nitem,
                                navitem2,
                                navitem3,
                                topic,
                                paper,
                                category,
                                navitem4
                                })
                            })
                       
                        })
                      
                         })
                     
                      
                     })
                
                })
               
  
              })
               
  
          })
  
      })
  }
  })
  

  router.get('/', checklogin, async (req, res) => {
 
    if(!(req.user && req.user.role === "user")){
      res.sendStatus(401);
    }else{
    Title.findAll()
      .then(title => {
        //console.log(title);
        NavItems.findAll()
          .then(nitem => {
            NavItem2.findAll()
              .then(navitem2 => {
                NavItem3.findAll()
                .then(navitem3 => {
                     PaperTopic.findAll()
                     .then(topic =>{
                      
                      Paper.findAll({
                        limit: 3,
                        order: [
                                  ['postingDate', 'DESC'],
                                  ['postingTime', 'DESC']
  
                        ],
                        include:[{
                          model: PaperTopic,
                          //required: true
                     
                        },{
                          model:Category
                        }]
                      })
                      .then(paper=>{
  
                         Category.findAll()
                         .then(category=>{
  
                            NavItem4.findAll()
                            .then(navitem4=>{
                              //console.log(JSON.stringify(paper, null, 2))
                              res.render('home/index', {
                                layout: 'index-layout',
                                title,
                                nitem,
                                navitem2,
                                navitem3,
                                topic,
                                paper,
                                category,
                                navitem4
                                })
                            })
                       
                        })
                      
                         })
                     
                      
                     })
                
                })
               
  
              })
               
  
          })
  
      })
  }
  })

module.exports = router
```

This is my login route

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

     if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      res.render('auth/login',{
        error_msg: 'Please Give Email And Password',
        layout: false
    })
    }
    else {
      User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } })
        .then(user => {
          if (!user) {
            res.render('auth/login',{
                error_msg: 'This Email Is Not Registered',
                layout: false
            })
          } else {
  
                    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) {
                        const token = jwt.sign({
                            username: user.name,
                            email: user.email,
                            role: user.role
                        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
                            expiresIn: '1h'
                        });
                       
                        res.cookie('ntoken', token,{
                            httpOnly:true
                        })
                        res.redirect('/');
                      

                    }
                    else {
                        res.render('auth/login',{
                            error_msg: 'Invalid Password',
                            layout: false
                        })
                    }

                });
            }

        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  
    }
  
  })
```

In this way I tried. But I didn't get any user.
Initially in my app.js file, I tried to call app.use(checklogin) like the following way

```
 app.use(checklogin)
    app.use('/', home);
    app.use('/auth', auth)
    app.use('/admin', admin)
    app.use('/home', homepage)
    app.use('/user', user);
```

before calling home, auth, admin routes with app.use(). But it didn't load the index page. It said internal server error. Then I tried with the following by skipping the middleware.

```
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/auth', auth)
app.use('/admin', admin)
app.use('/home', homepage)
app.use('/user', user);
```

Then, the index loads perfectly. Then after login I redirect to '/' .
and wrote the '/' with the checklogin middleware. After login I got cookie in the browser but no user in the hbs page.

[@76484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3397771/76484)
This is my middleware with new logic

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const checklogin = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.ntoken;
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      if (!decoded) { return next(); }
  
      const { username, email, role } = decoded;
      //const user = { email, role, username };
  
      //req.user = user; // attach the user to `req` for use in our route handlers
      //res.locals.user = user; // attach the user to `res.locals` for use in our views
      req.username = username;
      req.email = email;
      req.role = role;
   
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      //res.sendStatus(500);
      return next()
    }
  
    return next();
  };

  module.exports = checklogin;
```

This is my '/' route handler.

```
router.get('/', checklogin, async (req, res) => {
    
        if(req.role === "admin"){
            
            res.render('home/index', {
                       layout: 'index-layout',
                       name: req.username,
                       email: req.email,
                       role: req.role,
                       title,
                       nitem,
                       navitem2,
                       navitem3,
                       topic,
                       paper,
                       category,
                       navitem4
                       })
                                  })
                            
        }
        else if(req.role === "user"){
            
        }else{
           
        }
        
    
    })
    
    module.exports = router
```

I checked for role in every routes like the above mentioned way. And finally  I managed to get the desired output. I had to put return next() in the catch block to load the index page initially as index was not loaded due to the absence of token. I have tried your logic too but it didn't work.

Comment: I believe that in your User Middleware you should be setting the user values to `res.locals`. For example, `res.locals.email = email`. See: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals

Comment: @76484 Hi Thanks . I tried but nothing worked. In the middleware function I wrote
 the following
  res.locals.username = username;
     res.locals.email = email;
     req.locals.role = role;
     if(res.locals.role == "user"){
      next();
     }else{
        next("Require User Role");
     } 
In the root route with middleware, I tried to print data as console.log(res.locals.email) and wrote  res.render('home/index', { email: res.locals.email}) . But nothing worked.

Comment: By adding the variables to `res.locals`, you should not need to set them in your route handler in the `.render` call - they will already be made available to your views. When you say "nothing worked", what result are you getting?

Comment: @76484 Basically I wanted to redirect to '/' after login.  Initially there is a '/' route with no middleware and token. After login I want to verify the token using jwt.verify(). Then based on the role(user/admin) I want to redirect to '/'. I have other routes such as /admin, /user. Without login, if I hit /admin, /user  or '/ ',  it will show Invalid token. If I login as admin and hit /user it will show "no access". I wanted to implement this kind of scenario. Please help me out. I have modified my code too in the question section. Please check .

Comment: Is there anything different between the three handlers for the `/` GET request other than the middleware applied?

Comment: @76484 middleware is used to check the authenticate and authorized person after login. Only '/' route is without middleware. I want to persist the logged in the '/' route without middleware. Sorry for the disturb. May be I couldn't explain my problem to you.  please co-operate .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of unnecessary duplication in your code. For one example, the `isAdmin` and `isUser` middleware functions appear to be identical but for the `role` they check for. We want to avoid this duplication.

Secondly, you will need to include a middleware with your `/` GET handler that will in some way make the authenticated user object (if one exists) available to your code that renders the response.

What I would suggest is having a single middleware function that adds the user to the `req` object. We could call it `addUser`:

```
const addUser = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    if (!decoded) { return next(); }

    const { username, email, role } = decoded;
    const user = { email, role, username };

    req.user = user; // attach the user to `req` for use in our route handlers
    res.locals.user = user; // attach the user to `res.locals` for use in our views
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }

  return next();
};
```

We can attach this middleware to all of our route handlers with:

```
app.use(addUser);
```

Specific handlers will then need to check the `user` object for any conditional logic they need to apply. For example:

```
app.get("/admin", async (req, res) => {
  if (!(req.user && req.user.role === "admin")) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  } else {
    res.send("Hello, Admin");
  }
});
```

And since we have added the `user` object (when it exists) to `res.locals`, it is available in our view:

```
{{#if user}}
  {{#test user.role "admin"}}
    <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/admin/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{user.name}}</a></li>
  {{else}} 
    <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/user/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{user.name}}</a></li>               
  {{/test}}
{{else}}
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="/auth/register">Register Now!</a></li>
{{/if}}
```

As we have added the `user` object to `res.locals` and applied the middleware to all handlers, there is not much to be done to the "root" route handler. It would look something like:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home/index", {
    /* non-user variables */
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you mate for suggestion. Can you please write logic for '/' route. as you write for '/admin' . I got confused here.

Comment: @Shabnam: I have added a point about that to the end of my post. There isn't much that needs to be done here, assuming the controller does not have logic that depends on the `user`.

Comment: Thanks I saw the logic. But where I will redirect after login?  Sorry for disturb.

Comment: @Shabnam: Wherever you want your users to land, presumably to `/`.

Comment: Hi, I tried but nothing worked so far. I mention you in my post please checkout my new modifications. And ignore the grammar and spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Shabnam: The point that I am trying to get across is that you shouldn't have three handlers for the `/` route; you should have one and it should use the new middleware. The new middleware will add the user (if one can be decoded from the JWT) to the `req` object and `res.locals`. In the handler, you can perform any conditional logic based on the type of user.

Comment: I understand the point . I make one '/ ' handler but when I put  checklogin middleware  in the '/' handler then index page is not loading initially. It says internal server error. Then I put return next (); in catch block. then it index loads perfectly.   But res.locals. didn't wok. I wrote other logic.  and it worked finally. please check my post, I mentioned you